# Add a span to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, innerhtml

I have an array that I would like to form each element and add a span to it. I achieve it but I am not sure is the best way. Would be great to hear your opinions.
What I did?
I create 2 different strings.

```js
const one = `I am the <span class="red">first</span>`
const two = `I am the <span class="red">second</span>`
```

The class red puts the color red on the span. Now I need to change the strings to an array and add them to the HTML.

```js
const three = one.split();
const four= two.split();
const five = four.concat(three);

let i = 0;
myhtml.innerHTML = five[ i % five.length]
i +=1;
```

This works. If I put it inside a function looks, clean and all but...There is a better way? I found some way to add a span to arrays but they didn't seem the easiest to achieve.
The thing is I am not a big fan of innerHTML so could all this be done in a new way?
what are your thoughts?

Comment: What's the reason for splitting the strings? Why not just `five = one + two`?

Comment: What is wrong with `myhtml.innerHTML = one + two`?

Comment: The idea is that each string would show in the HTML at the time, over and over. So first would show `I am the <span class="red">first</span>` and then  `I am the <span class="red">second</span>` and then again the first one, always looping

Comment: Is there supposed to be a loop here? Why are you just putting one character into the innerHTML?

Comment: @RicardoMoreira In such a case you could use `five = [one, two]`, instead of splitting and concatenating.

Comment: @3limin4t0r true that. I forgot about that, been away from ES6 for a while. It saves me lines for sure. Thanks